# RegEx find unique words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse string in JavaScript and find all unique words, which starts with `:` symbol. I wrote that regular expression for this purpose:

```
/(:[A-z]\w+)(?!.*\1)/g
```

It works fine for this string:

```
"test :one :one test :one test :two".match(/(:[A-z]\w+)(?!.*\1)/g)
```

And result is `[':one', ':two']` [Online example #1](https://regex101.com/r/sC8eA9/1)

But, if after word goes *new line* symbol

```
"test :one\n :one test :one test :two".match(/(:[A-z]\w+)(?!.*\1)/ig)
```

Regex not working properly and returns `[':one', ':one', ':two']` [Online example #2](https://regex101.com/r/sC8eA9/2)

How to modify this regex and get only unique results?

Comment: `[A-z]` vs `[A-Z]`

Comment: @Tushar, thx, I'll fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` to make sure the check may go as far as the end of *string* (not just line) and `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[A-z]` (see [**Why is this regex allowing a caret?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)):

```
/(:[a-z]\w+)(?![\s\S]*\1)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT5nR6/1)

```js
var re = /(:[a-z]\w+)(?![\s\S]*\1)/gi; 
var str = 'test :one\n :one test :one test :two';
console.log(str.match(re));
//or, get rid of the inital :
console.log(str.match(re).map(function(x){return x.substr(1);}));
```

Comment: Just in case: I added another line of code to get rid of the initial `:`s if you need that. Certainly it can be done with inner capturing group and then iterate through the matches with `RegExp#exec`, but why not reuse your code.